# Saving pictures to disk from for loop in R

Tags: r, image, loops

Here is the problem. A want to save pictures, that generates my loop. But it doesnt work.

Here is my code

```
> for(i in 1:2){
+ pdf(filename="a[i].pdf")
+ plot(Q[[i]],W[[i]], main=a[i])
+ dev.off()
+ }
```

where a is names vector, Q and W are lists of two vectors, where 
length(Q[i])=length(W[i]). 
The issue is:

```
Error in pdf(filename = "a[i].pdf") : 
unused argument (filename = "a[i].pdf")
```

Thx for tips.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the argument names in `?pdf`. The correct name is `file`, not `filename`. You will also probably want something like `sprintf` to construct dynamic name(s), e.g. `sprintf("my_file[%d].pdf", 1:5)`.

Comment: Thx a lot, but i dont understand the     sprintf()    argument. Can you explaint it please?

Comment: @Bobesh the `%d` will be replaced by an integer. I used 1:5, but you will put `i` instead. Run the command in the console and see how it works. Also, see the help file. It should be all there.